# How do I compile Flash app files with mxml and as extensions?

Tags: flash, mxml

What should I do to stand up my project with .mxml and .as files in intellij idea with flash app?

I checked chatgpt and queries in different derivatives, but I could not get the result I wanted, the project did not compile.

Comment: **Adobe Flash Builder** (or its previous versions known as **Adobe Flex Builder**) works with MXML/AS source files and builds SWF or AIR applications from them.

Comment: I'm also having problems installing Adobe flash builder. so I'm trying to install the dependencies in intellij idea but I think I can't because it's complicated.